# Unsupported node 'item' in file style.xml

Tags: android, xml, node.js

> Execution failed for task':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Unsupported node 'item' in file

I'm having this kind of error and the answer that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941750/gradle-fail-unsupported-node-item-in-ids-xml) can't answer my problem.

This is my styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

<!--  ************************
 ||||||||||||||||||||||||
          HEADER
 ||||||||||||||||||||||||
 ************************  -->
<style name="Header.TitleText" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo">
    <item name="android:fontFamily" tools:ignore="NewApi">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:textColor" >@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#8000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">5</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">2</item>
</style>

<style name="Header.SubTitleText" parent="Header.TitleText">
    <item name="android:fontFamily" tools:ignore="NewApi">sans-serif-condensed</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mistake is on this line

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
```

every item has to be defined between the open and close style tags. In your case they are outside. You should have

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
  <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

instead of

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
   <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
   <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
   <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: Thank u  perfect solution.